# How to pass value of a dropdown menu from jsp to controller in spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

My index page

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="0"
                data-toggle="dropdown" value="1" name="techid">Development</a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="sub2">
                    <p style="text-align: center; width: 100%">ApplicationDevelopment

                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="./CheckYourself?=11" 
                 name=roleid value="1">Developer</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenudeveloper">
                            <p id="fundamentaltechtext">
                                Fundamentals&emsp;&emsp;|&emsp;&emsp;Technology<br> </br>
                            <p>
```

While passing the name "techid" and "roleid "am getting null value in controller. Please let me know how to get the value as i written in my jsp.

My controller

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController 
{
    @Autowired
    private QuestionDelegate questionDelegate;

      //Check yourself page launch

    public QuestionDelegate getQuestionDelegate() {
        return questionDelegate;
    }
    public void setQuestionDelegate(QuestionDelegate questionDelegate) {
        this.questionDelegate = questionDelegate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/CheckYourself",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displaycheckyourself(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("arul") sample samplebean)
    {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("CheckYourself");
    samplebean.getRoleid();
    samplebean.getTechid();
    int techid;
    int roleid;
 //   questionDelegate.setQuestion( techid, roleid);
    model.addObject("samplebean", samplebean);
    return model;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass `roleid` and `techid` directly from Controller

Your new Controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/CheckYourself",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displaycheckyourself(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("CheckYourself");
        // retrieve your sample bean
        model.addObject("roleid", samplebean.getRoleid());
        model.addObject("techid", samplebean.getTechid());
        return model;
    }
```

In jsp page you can access it like this

```
name="${techid}"
```